# Table pagination with datable or only mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pagination, datatables, html-table

I'm trying to make a pagination system for a table with datas from mongoose.
Actually I know how to do it but I wonder which method is the best :

**Method 1: Only with mongoose**

```
var perPage = 15
, page = req.param('page') > 0 ? req.param('page') -1 : 0
res.locals.createPagination = function (pages, page) {
    var url = require('url')
    , qs = require('querystring')
    , params = qs.parse(url.parse(req.url).query)
    , str = ''

    params.page = 1
    for (var p = 1; p < pages + 1; p++) {
        params.page = p
        clas = page+1 == p ? "active" : "no"
        str += '<li class="'+clas+'"><a href="?'+qs.stringify(params)+'">'+ p +'</a></li>'
    }
    return str
}
        Vente.find({})
        .populate({ path: 'user_id', select: 'username server -_id'})
        .limit(perPage)
        .skip(perPage * page)
        .sort({created_at: 'desc'})
        .exec(function(err, ventes){
            Vente.count({}, function(err, count){
                res.render('index', {
                    page: page,
                    pages: count / perPage,
                    user: req.user,
                    items: ventes,
                });
            });
        });
})
```

and in my jade file i have this :

```
if (pages > 1)
    ul.pagination
      != createPagination(pages, page)
```

It works very well, I send to the jade file only 15 elements.

**Method 2: With Datatable** 
In my .jade file I just have to add :

```
script(type="text/javascript")
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#tab").dataTable();
   });
script(type="text/javascript",src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
```

But I have to send to my .jade all elements

So my question is : Is the First method better ? The second method let the user search faster and pagination doesn't need to refresh the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable is very cool (I personally use it). Luckily Datatable has a way to load the content server side, it is cool because you get a lot of stuff for free. Probably just a matter of changing a bit the way you return the data.

Method 2, loading everything, will just not work in the long run, too much data to load.

Method 1, is ok, but I would go with a mix of the two. DataTable server side, as explained above.